# Customize traceback output

Tags: python, exception, logging, error-handling, traceback

I use this code to write into a `.log` file when there is an uncaught exception :

```
import sys
import traceback

def uncaught_exc_handler(ex_cls, ex, tb):
   with open('mylog.log', 'w') as f: 
      traceback.print_last(file=f)

sys.excepthook = uncaught_exc_handler

1/0
```

**Exemple of output :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

**How to customize the logging and have this instead :**

```
ERROR 11 (test): ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

?

*(note :  `11` is the number of the line where the error occured, `test` is the current file)*

*PS : I thought about parsing these 4 lines, search for "line" in the second line, extract the `int` nearby, etc.   but that's a rather dirty method, and I imagine this won't work robustly*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you need:

```
import sys
import traceback

def uncaught_exc_handler(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    last_traceback = (traceback.extract_tb(tb))[-1]
    line_number = last_traceback[1]
    file_name = last_traceback[0].split(".")[0]
    class_name = ex_cls.__name__
    with open('mylog.log', 'w') as f: 
        f.write("ERROR %s (%s) %s: %s\n" % (line_number, file_name, class_name, str(ex)))

sys.excepthook = uncaught_exc_handler


1/0
```

Which results in a file (`mylog.log`) that contains the line:

```
ERROR 15 (test) ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```